# Is it possible to pass a different postgresql.conf when calling psql?

Tags: psql

Am reading documentation on [psql config file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html), specifically section "20.1.2. Parameter Interaction via the Configuration File". Am also [reading psql params](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-psql.html).

My question is, when calling psql in the terminal, is there a way or convention of passing a custom config file to use with the query as opposed to the default?

e.g. something like `psql --config path/to/my/config.conf`?

I would like to pass args such as the host, port, not the password.

Comment: `postgresql.conf` configures the **server** it has nothing to do with the `psql` client. To pass a different host or port use `-h` or `-p`

Comment: OK, thanks for this info. Is there a concept of a conf file that I can use in my desired way (Just came from a snowsql set up which used a conf file, wondered if there's a similar set up with psql)

Comment: i.e. rather than set host and port on every call to psql, can I have defaults set up, e.g. in a config?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.20.10 or use [environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)

Comment: Ah OK, I need `psqlrc` file. Thanks!

Comment: Btw: `postgresql.conf` is not the "psql config file" - it's the "PostgreSQL config file". psql is not the same thing as PostgreSQL

Comment: Okay? My understanding is that I use psql to query a Postgres db via the terminal. Is that correct?